# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult" в "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**MVC6**

> Ошибка    CS0029  Не удается неявно преобразовать тип
>   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.RedirectToActionResult" в
>   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult"

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int idgame, string returnUrl)
{
    Game game = repositorygame.Games
        .FirstOrDefault(g => g.id == idgame);

    if (game != null)
    {
        cart.AddItem(game, 1);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` возвращает `RedirectToActionResult`. Ваш метод пытается вернуть его как `RedirectToRouteResult`.

`RedirectToActionResult` и `RedirectToRouteResult` - это два разных типа. Поменяйте свой метод на возврат нужного типа

```
public RedirectToActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int idgame, string returnUrl)
```

или на возврат базового типа

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int idgame, string returnUrl)
```

и не пишите код наугад. Это же основы языка, их стоит освоить до того, как писать на C# что-нибудь сложное.

---

В MVC5 `RedirectToAction` возвращал `RedirectToRouteResult`. В MVC6 для него выделили отдельный тип `RedirectToActionResult`. Оба типа являются наследниками `ActionResult`, так что указание его в качестве возвращаемого типа будет работать и в 5 и в 6-й версии.

Comment: Код рабочий и взят отсюда


http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/gamestore/level2/2_6.php


Но не работат после переноса на новый аспнет.

Comment: @mk000000000 вот про это я и говорю - это тривиальная ошибка, которых при переносе с MVC5 -> MVC6 будет много - слишком уж сильно поменялась платформа. Многие вещи придется просто переписывать, включая работу с сессией (она поменялась, да и не место ей в ModelBinder-е, imho). Если вы пытаетесь освоить MVC - осваивайте его на стабильной 5-й версии (asp.net 4 / mvc 5)